US agencies phone numbers in the 1960s-1970s
For those who have a memory of it, I would like to understand the structure of the numbering plans and phone numbers of US agencies in the 1960s-1970s.
In an old congressional phonebook from 1971
I see entries like

Migratory Bird Conservation Commission
United States Department of the Interior Building
Phone, 343-4676 (Code 183, extension 4676)
CENTRAL INTELLIGENCE AGENCY
Washington, D.C. 20505, Phone, 351-1100 (Code 143)
DOMESTIC COUNCIL
1600 Pennsylvania Avenue 20500. Phone, 456-1414 (Code 145)
NATIONAL SECURITY COUNCIL
Old Executive Office Building, 20506. Phone, 395-3000 (Code 103, extension 3440)

I would like to understand what are the "Codes" that are mentioned on a lot of those entities.
What was the name of those codes and is there a comprehensive list somewhere ?
Was that tied to a specific network like the FTS (Federal Telecommunications System) ? how did you call a number ?
In the case of the DOMESTIC COUNCIL. Phone, 456-1414 (Code 145), was it 456-1414+145 + extension or something else ?

The question is more likely to get an answer if the title asks a clear question (who what where, etc.)

I do not remember ‘code’ as a part of the regular phone system of my childhood. However, there may have been a way to place the call internally to the government switchboard using the ‘code’ as shorthand for the longer number, and also keeping the call on internal hardware. For years my government lab had a set of somewhat similar shortcuts to commonly used services.

Earlier incarnation of CGAC maybe? Or do you know for a fact that these codes are actually related to the phone system specifically, and if so, how?

@BrianZ - I did a quick check, and I don't think its likely to be that, due to the timing (and the numbers used). My current theory is it was an internal number for US Government phones inside their internal phone system. For instance, at my company I can reach any other desk phone by typing the last 4 digits of its phone #. To dial a number outside the system, I have to dial 9, wait for a new dialtone, then dial the number.

Please type phone numbers consistent with 1971 usage - long before 10-digit dialing, so the area code was used only for direct-dial long distance, and hence was in parentheses when typed. The exchange was separated from the local number with a dash, so as to easily recognize long distance numbers within the same area code - as exchanges were a physical location with a physical wire connection to the customer's phone(s).

I’m a bit surprised with the exchange being all numbers. In my suburban Philadelphia childhood the alphanumeric abbreviations extended into the late 70s phone books if memory serves (which it often does not, sigh). MU8 (688) for Murray-8 and so forth.

This system is meant to be a shortcut for calling within the government dialing system. It is explained on page 94 of a Telephone Directory published by the US Congress and Senate in 1965.

Interdepartmental dial equipment permits government telephone users to
make interdepartmental calls direct to extensions in certain without
the help of an operator This system called Through Dialing. To call an
extension in an agency equipped for through dialing the government
employee dials the agency code followed by the extension
number desired. There will be no second dial tone following the
dialed code. To reach an information operator the employee dials the
code for the agency desired followed by O

The next several pages following are a listing of the various agency codes.
Note the code for the CIA appears on the same linked page, matching the info given in the question above:

Central Intelligence Agency             143

